# Bad Substitution error bin/sh

Tags: arrays, unix, sh

The following snippet is part of a xyz.sh file

```
#! /bin/sh
TIMESTAMP=$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M)
TIMESTAMPACTUAL=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
set P6_84

VMs=$1
VMsCount=${#VMs[@]}
echo "ARAAY: $VMs"
```

I am getting bad substitution error for the follwoing statement when I try to run the file as ./xyz.sh

`VMsCount=${#VMs[@]}`

Please help to debug it.

Comment: What happens if you change the first line to `#!/usr/bin/bash`?

Comment: -sh: ./xyz.sh: not found

Comment: Ah, so you don't even have bash. What's your shell, and does it support arrays?

Comment: what i see is Bourne Shell only

Comment: Where do you see that?

Comment: `/bin/sh` is typically an alias for another shell (`bash` and `dash` are two common implementations), and a script run by `/bin/sh` is supposed to adhere to the [POSIX shell specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/xcu.html). Arrays are not defined by POSIX, however.

Comment: @AbhinavPrakash, `#!/bin/sh` is not Bourne on modern platforms, it's POSIX sh. The only *remotely* modern platform to ship 1970s-era Bourne is Solaris, and even they fixed it as of Solaris 10.